# MissingMethodException: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setAliases() during Grails run-app

Tags: grails

I get the below error when i run a grails application. By looking to error trace is someone able to recognize what this errors cause could be?

it seems for me that grails is unable to start the tomcat embedded server for some reason. i use grails 1.3.4 in a linux system (openSuse 12.1)

--UPDATE--

I use openJDK version 6:

```
 java version "1.6.0_24"

 OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (suse-3.1-i386)

 OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

--Error Trace---

```
(stuff leftout)

Error executing script RunApp: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setAliases() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/plugins/log4j-xml-0.2=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/log4j-xml-0.2/./web-app,/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.7=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.7/./web-app,/plugins/remote-pagination-0.2.4=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/remote-pagination-0.2.4/./web-app,/plugins/remoting-1.1=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/remoting-1.1/./web-app,/plugins/jquery-1.4.4.1=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/jquery-1.4.4.1/./web-app,/plugins/include-0.3=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/include-0.3/./web-app]
Possible solutions: getClass(), setName(java.lang.String), setDocBase(java.lang.String), setName(java.lang.String)
11:16:42,037 ERROR [StackTrace] Sanitizing stacktrace:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.setAliases() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [/plugins/log4j-xml-0.2=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/log4j-xml-0.2/./web-app,/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.7=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/jquery-ui-1.8.7/./web-app,/plugins/remote-pagination-0.2.4=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/remote-pagination-0.2.4/./web-app,/plugins/remoting-1.1=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/remoting-1.1/./web-app,/plugins/jquery-1.4.4.1=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/jquery-1.4.4.1/./web-app,/plugins/include-0.3=/home/othman/.grails/1.3.4/projects/jbilling/plugins/include-0.3/./web-app]
Possible solutions: getClass(), setName(java.lang.String), setDocBase(java.lang.String), setName(java.lang.String)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.<init>(TomcatServer.groovy:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:77)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:107)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:192)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:212)
    at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServerFactory.createInline(TomcatServerFactory.groovy:10)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrap.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:246)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:115)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1003)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:163)
    at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:289)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor135.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor134.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor128.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1003)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:706)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1123)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor127.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor126.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1104)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1060)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:706)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1123)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:147)
    at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:289)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1003)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:706)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1123)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1017)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:159)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:289)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:276)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:271)
    at groovy.lang.Closure$call.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:40)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:121)
    at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
    at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
    at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
    at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:88)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1058)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1070)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:886)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:708)
    at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObject$invokeMethod.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:155)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:51)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:44)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:143)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:155)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeWithGantInstance(GrailsScriptRunner.java:656)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.callPluginOrGrailsScript(GrailsScriptRunner.java:522)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.executeCommand(GrailsScriptRunner.java:318)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.GrailsScriptRunner.main(GrailsScriptRunner.java:135)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.rootLoader(GrailsStarter.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.support.GrailsStarter.main(GrailsStarter.java:262)


[other stuff ..]
```

Comment: Which jdk are you using?

Comment: see my update for the java jdk information.

Comment: Have you recently installed any plugins or upgraded the grails version of your app? or is this a fresh project?

Comment: @David, no i just freshly installed a default grails 1.3.4 . the project i want to build from source and it is a fresh project. this is first installation of grails and first attempt to run my project.

Comment: Did you create your project with grails create-app, or did you copy this project and tried to run-app it? Just trying to determine if any call to a grails script will result in this error.

Comment: Do you have GRAILS_HOME defined?

Comment: i have GRAILS_HOME defined. i didn't created project with grails create-app .it is a packaged grails project that i unzip the source and tried building it.

Comment: Can you try grails help or grails create-app dummy ?